# Installing DSC resource nxComputerManagement and nxNetworking on Windows Server 2012 R2 WMF 4.0

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, dsc

I am trying to install the two new DSC resources for Linux nxComputerManagement and nxNetworking on Windows Server 2012 R2 machine with WMF 4.0, but when i do a Get-DSCResource or a Get-Module -Listavailable i dont see the modules listed in the output.

[image]

On my win 10 machine with WMF 5.0 installed i was able to install this module by using the Save-Module and Install-Module cmdlets. When i did a Get-DSCResource on my win10 machine i saw that the nxComputerManagement and nxNetworking was getting saved at `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

so in my win2k12r2 machine with WMF 4.0 i did the similar thing, copied over the modules from my Win 10 machine to `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` location of the win2k12r2 machine, also appended a new path to PSmodulePath

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
```

Even after adding this the modules are not getting detected / the Import-DSCResource cmdlets are not detecting these modules.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, deleted all the nx* modules i had copied over to "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules". next installed the PSGet Module from https://www.powershellgallery.com/, and then installed the modules using Install-module cmdlet to get them working.

[image]